# How to change the values of variables when processing events from another class?javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

There is a class with a handler that calculates the direction - InputManager.

How do I change the values of variables in the main Game class each time process an event in the InputManager?

On the [codepen](https://codepen.io/zemil/pen/jYOmeM?editors=0010) or:

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 4;
    this.score = 0;

    this.inputManager = new InputManager;
  }

}

class InputManager {
  constructor() {
    this.mouseDown_position = {};
    this.events = {};
    this.listen();
  }

  listen() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.mouseDown_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      let mouseUp_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
      let deltaX = this.mouseDown_position.x - mouseUp_position.x,
          deltaY = this.mouseDown_position.y - mouseUp_position.y;

      // Move directions:
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX > 0) {
        console.log('left');
      }
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX < 0) {
        console.log('right');
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: What is "the main Game class"?  What values are you trying to change?  Where are you trying to change them?  How are you trying to change them?

Comment: @David, InputManager console.log directions, I want to pass the directions to Game class and change the value of any variable in the class Game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is that you pass the Game context to the InputManager, and from there you can manipulate the variable.

This is not encapsulation done right.

In theory Game should have a function to update the score, and InputManager should call that function to update the score (or use a similar approach for other variables).

```js
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 4;
    this.score = 10;
    this.inputManager = new InputManager(this);
    this.direction = this.inputManager.direction;
    console.log(this.direction);
  }
}

class InputManager {
  constructor(gC) {
    console.log(gC.score);
    this.gC = gC;
    this.mouseDown_position = {};
    this.events = {};
    this.direction = null;
    this.listen();
  }

  listen() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
      this.mouseDown_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
    });

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => { 
    
      this.gC.score++;
      console.log(this.gC.score);
      
      let mouseUp_position = {
        x : event.clientX,
        y : event.clientY
      };
      let deltaX = this.mouseDown_position.x - mouseUp_position.x,
          deltaY = this.mouseDown_position.y - mouseUp_position.y;

      // MOVE DIRECTION:
      // LEFT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX > 0) {
        console.log('left');
        this.direction = 'left';
      }
      // RIGHT
      if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX < 0) {
        console.log('right');
        this.direction = 'right';
      }
      // UP
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
        console.log('up');
        this.direction = 'up';
      }
      // DOWN
      if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY < 0) {
        console.log('down');
        this.direction = 'down';
      }
    });

  }
}

var game = new Game();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.size = 4;
    this.score = 0;
    this.changesize = (size) => {
      this.size = size;
    }

    this.inputManager = new InputManager(changesize);
  }

 class InputManager(){
     constructor(changesize){
       [...]
       this.changeSize = changesize;
       this.changeSize(300);
       [...]
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to supply a reference to `InputManager` which refers back to the `Game` instance.  For example, suppose `InputManager` required this reference on its constructor:

```
class InputManager {
  constructor(game) {
    this.game = game; // <-- store it locally here
    this.mouseDown_position = {};
    this.events = {};
    this.listen();
  }

  //...
```

Then when creating an instance of `InputManager`, your `Game` class could pass a reference to itself:

```
this.inputManager = new InputManager(this);
```

With that reference, anywhere in `InputManager` you can modify the values on that instance.  Something as simple as:

```
this.game.score++;
```

From here you can further refactor to invoke operations in the objects instead of modifying values directly, you can pass closures to wrap access to the values, etc.  But the main point is that you'd simply need some reference back to what you want to modify.

Comment: Are there another ways to call a function in Game class when events happen in InputManager class?

Comment: @Эмиль: You can invoke any operation you'd like from that reference.  For example, if the `Game` class defines a function called `applyBonus()` then you could call that function exactly the same way: `this.game.applyBonus();`  That reference is literally just a variable for a `Game` object.  It works like any variable.